# Ошибка при исполнении простого выражения Haskell (ветвление)

Tags: haskell

Требуется реализовать функцию, которая возвращает 1, если ей передано положительное число, (-1), если отрицательное, и 0 в случае, когда передан 0.

```
let fff x = (if x<0 then -1 else(if x>0 then 1 else 0))
```

Работает только с положительными числами и нулем. Когда передаю отрицательное число - ругается вот так

```
<interactive>:6:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> p)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a p. (Ord a, Num a, Num p, Num (a -> p)) => a -> p
```

В чем состоит моя ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотя вы и не привели этого в своём вопросе, я догадываюсь, что "передать отрицательное число" вы пытаетесь вот так:

```
fff -1
```

Такая запись понимается компилятором не как "*вызвать функцию `fff` с аргументом `-1`*", а как "*вычесть 1 из `fff`*"

Чтобы вызвать функцию с отрицательным аргументом, используйте скобки:

```
fff (-1)
```